# Flatten a unserialized nested json data having multilevel dictionary nesting at large

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

```
I Have data structure like the one mentioned below which us all nested in terms of dictionaries : 
{
'list':{
'5':{
'set_profile_type':'static',
'status_name_now':'OFF',
'name':'BTテザリング',
'status_code_now':'OFF',
'status_name_init':'OFF',
'status_list':{
'0':{},
'1':{}
},
'guide':'some utf text',
'choice_type':'select',
'get_profile':'BTtethering_GetOnOff',
'status_key_name':'onOff'
},
'4':{
'set_profile_type':'static',
'status_name_now':'OFF',
'name':'WiFiテザリング',
'status_code_now':'OFF',
'status_name_init':'OFF',
'status_list':{
'0':{},
'1':{}
},
'guide':'UTF text',
'choice_type':'select',
'get_profile':'PortableHotspot_GetOnOff',
'status_key_name':'onOff'
},
'2':{},
'0':{},
'6':{},
'1':{},
'3':{}
},
'name':'somePropert1'
}
```

while I am trying to flatten this structure into a csv, I have tried pandas library with json.loads, the above string is formed as a result of ohpserialization library i have used unserialize; is there a nice and clean way to flatten this data structure I have also tried json_normalize but that doesn't recognize above string as json-

```
    def deserialize(data):
    import phpserialize
    import ast
    import json
    data = "'"+data+"'"
    data = ast.literal_eval(format(data)).encode('utf-8')
    j1 = phpserialize.unserialize(data)
    j1 = phpserialize.loads(phpserialize.dumps(j1), decode_strings=True)
    j1 = json.dumps(j1)
    return j1
    def CustomParser(data):
    import json
    j1 = json.loads(data)
    j1 = j1
    return j1
    df = pandas.read_csv(input_file,sep="|",converters=
    {'device_udate':deserialize},header=0)
    print (df)
    df.to_csv(output_file,sep=",",encoding="utf-8")
    df1 = pandas.read_csv(output_file,converters=
    {'device_udate':CustomParser},header=0)
    df1[sorted(df1['device_udate'][0].keys())] = 
    df1['device_udate'].apply(pandas.Series)
    print (df1)
```

Comment: Is `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['list']).T.dropna()` what you're looking for?

Comment: well I doubt, because the source data is already a part of dataframe i am reading it from df and parsing it to my customParser function